# How can I add a boolean variable to the ngClass in Angular? When the div is created dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to keep the div's being created dynamically. I need each div to have it's own variable so I can flip one variable without affecting the other divs. Also I can't use jquery. I know using vanilla javascript in Angular is not a best practice.

For example the html code:

```
<div *ngFor="let n of numbers">
    <div [ngClass]="____ ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{n}}</div>
</div>
```

And the typescript code:

```
numbers: string[] = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
```

The above code will create the below:

```
<div [ngClass]="_________ ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{1}}</div>
<div [ngClass]="_________ ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{2}}</div>
<div [ngClass]="_________ ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{3}}</div>
<div [ngClass]="_________ ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{4}}</div>
<div [ngClass]="_________ ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{5}}</div>
<div [ngClass]=“_________ ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{6}}</div>
```

I need it to be the below:

```
<div [ngClass]="variable1 ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{1}}</div>
<div [ngClass]="variable2 ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{2}}</div>
<div [ngClass]="variable3 ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{3}}</div>
<div [ngClass]="variable4 ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{4}}</div>
<div [ngClass]="variable5 ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{5}}</div>
<div [ngClass]=“variable6 ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{6}}</div>
```

Instead of the ____ I need to know how to add different variables dynamically.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Use index to set variables then.

Comment: It won't let me use the index. I've tried that.

Answer (score 2):

You define the variable in your component class, and you can set a default value. You can update the value later in the init function or on some event.

```
someVarName: boolean = false;
```

In the HTML, you would write:

```
<div *ngFor="let n of numbers">
  <div [ngClass]="someVarName ? 'box' : 'hide'">{{n}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, nobody can help you without more context. What do you mean by "a different boolean values for each div"? How should this value be computed?